# How to have alternating long/short deals

Tags: pine-script, strategy-pattern

I am writing a strategy and I need to avoid repeating two long trades or two short trades in a row. That is long and short trades alternated. I tried using `strategy.closedtrades.size` but it didn't help, or i missed something.

I also add pyramiding, but it didn't help.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```PineScript
    // Davydov Strategy
    //@version=5
    strategy("Davydov Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=0)
    
    
    // Declaring stop loss (SL) take profit (TP)
    SL = input.float(0.5, "Stop loss", minval=0.1, maxval=100, step=0.1)
    TP = input.float(1, "Take profit", minval=0.1, maxval=100,step=0.1)
    
    // Interrupt the Long-Long / Short-Short cycle
    var count = 0
    longLong = strategy.closedtrades.size(0)>=0
    if longLong
    count := count + 1
    plot(count)
    
    // Condition Long
    
    // Price calculation for stop loss and take profit (Long)
    longStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(100-SL)/100
    longProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(100+TP)/100
    
    // Condition check
    if trend_strength > 0
        if Greenbar1 and Greenbar2 == 1 ? RsiMa2 - 50 : na
            if direction < 0 ? supertrend : na
                strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, na)
    
        // Conditions for closing a deal
    strategy.exit("Close","Long", stop=longStop, limit=longProfit, 
    when=strategy.position_size>=0)
    
    // Condition Short
    
        //Price calculation for stop loss and take profit
    shortStop = strategy.position_avg_price*(100+SL)/100
    shortProfit = strategy.position_avg_price*(100-TP)/100
    
        //  Condition check
    if trend_strength < 0
         if Redbar1 and Redbar2 == 1 ? RsiMa2 - 50 : na
            if direction < 0? na : supertrend
                strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, na)
    
        // Conditions for closing a deal    
    strategy.exit("exit","Short", stop=shortStop,limit=shortProfit, 
    when=strategy.position_size<=0)


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuCXU.png
```

Comment: But from the screenshot it looks like you have exit-entry-exit-entry, so it is alternating, no?

Comment: @vitruvius I need to prevent it, pyramiding didn't help. I need to trade: Long- Close Long - Short - Close Short...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getLastPosSign()` is helper function that you needs:

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = ta.crossunder(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)

getLastPosSign() =>
    strategy.closedtrades > 0 ? math.sign(strategy.closedtrades.size(strategy.closedtrades-1)) : na

plot( getLastPosSign(), style = plot.style_linebr )
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a very elegant solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't manage to attach this function to my script. In the example you posted, the value changes from -1 to 1 when the direction of the trade changes. In this case, I must write conditions that IF the past value is the same as the current one, then there is no need to open a deal. But how do you do it if it's a loop? @andreyd

Comment: Ideally, if we say that a deal always alternates and never repeats, then the value of the function should always be the same and remain the same as the value of the very first calculation. @andreyd

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand the root of your problem. Could you show it on concrete example?